# How do I get my random number to carry into an IF statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I need help trying to get a randomly generated number to carry into an 
IF statement.
This is commented to my best abilities to explain my problem, also I have 
simplified the comments to help newbies like me understand more easily whats 
going on. Plain text copy at bottom if its to messy as this is my fist 
question.

```
<body>

    //This button once clicked will call the function ranNum()
    <input type="button" onClick="ranNum()" value="Generate Random Number 
    Between 1 and 20" />

    //Where the randomly generated number is displayed ranNumber
    <p id="ranNumber"></p>

    /*Where the texted based on the Random Number generated is 
    displayed*/
    <p id="numText"></p>

    <script>

        //This is the start of the function
        function ranNum() {

                /*Here is where the Random Number is place in 
                the variable ranNumber and then written to the p tag with 
                the same id This happens once generated from the code 
                below*/
                document.getElementById("ranNumber").innerHTML =

               /*Here is where I get stuck, Ive tried to give the Random 
                Number a variable name GeneratedNumber but it doesnt seem 
                to carry through to the IF statement. If anyone can help 
                explain a simple fix which Im sure it is and a little 
                explanation. Id be very great full*/
                var GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

            /*Here I set a variable conclusion to be carried through the 
            IF statement.*/
            var conclusion

            /*Here I carried the variable GeneratedNumber which I thought 
            should hold the Random Number generated into the IF statement. 
            It was to display the text within the IF statement if the 
            number was equal to or below 10*/
            if (GeneratedNumber = < 10) {

                conclusion = "The number generated 'numbervar' is less than 
                or equal to 10"

            /*Here any number that didnt meet the above criteria was to 
            display the text below within the else*/
            } else {

                conclusion = "The number generated “numbervar” is greater 
                than 10"

            }

            /*Here the id numText is called to write the result of the IF 
            statement or the conclusion to the page*/
            document.getElementById("numText").innerHTML = conclusion;

        }

    </script>

</body>

//Plain copy of text with no comments

<body>


    <input type="button" onClick="ranNum()" value="Generate Random Number 
    Between 1 and 20" />

    <p id="ranNumber"></p>
    <p id="numText"></p>

    <script>

        function ranNum() {

            document.getElementById("ranNumber").innerHTML =
                var GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

            var conclusion

            if (GeneratedNumber = < 10) {

                conclusion = "The number generated 'numbervar' is less than 
                or equal to 10"

            } else {

                conclusion = "The number generated “numbervar” is greater 
                than 10"

            }

            document.getElementById("numText").innerHTML = conclusion;

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm confused with what you are asking. Generate your random number first and assign it to a variable. Then, as long as you are in the same scope (function), just refer to that variable anytime you need that random number. FYI: you are using HTML comments in JavaScript.

Comment: It's already answered, but here's a Fiddle with a concise `if` statement, since I already made it. http://jsfiddle.net/rp9w58y1

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes that's pretty much the intention of the code and thank you for pointing that out, I cant believe I over looked the code being commented wrong. My bad.

Comment: @mark.hch Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first response to a StackOverflow question, so sorry if some of the formatting is weird but there were some issues with scope in the original namely

```
   document.getElementById("ranNumber").innerHTML = GeneratedNumber = 
   Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
```

in addition to some of the comparison operators being used incorrectly for example (a = < 10) cannot be used in place of (a<=10) Lastly, I also changed the conclusion string to insert the number generated since that looked like a bug as well! Good luck coding

```
  function ranNum() {
    var GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    var conclusion
    if (GeneratedNumber <= 10) {
      conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is less than or equal to 10`;
    } else {
      conclusion = `The number generated ${GeneratedNumber} is greater than 10`;
    }
    document.getElementById("numText").innerHTML = conclusion;
  }
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. Which has explained a lot of what went wrong also you even noticed an oversight on my part which was displaying the random number generated so 10/10 for you, Thank you! Also just to add I was using this comparison operator in the preferred way but was told otherwise off my tutor, that is the only reason I switched the < = round. But I will go back to how I preferred it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues, please check your syntax! ;)

here is a very minimal improvement to just make your code work

```javascript

```
<script>

    function ranNum() {

        document.getElementById("ranNumber").innerHTML =
            GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

        var conclusion

        if (GeneratedNumber <= 10) {

            conclusion = "The number generated 'numbervar' is less than or equal to 10"

        } else {

            conclusion = "The number generated “numbervar” is greater than 10"

        }

        document.getElementById("numText").innerHTML = conclusion;

    }

</script>

    <input type="button" onClick="ranNum()" value="Generate Random Number 
Between 1 and 20" />

<p id="ranNumber"></p>
<p id="numText"></p>
```

```

Comment: `document.getElementById("ranNumber").innerHTML =   GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;` should be: `var GeneratedNumber 
 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1; document.getElementById("ranNumber").textContent = GeneratedNumber;`

Answer (score 0):

Just some minor mistakes in the code. This should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Fix</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" onClick="ranNum()" value="Generate Random Number 
  Between 1 and 20" />

  <p id="ranNumber"></p>
  <p id="numText"></p>

  <script>

      function ranNum() {

          //document.getElementById("ranNumber").innerHTML =
              var GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

          var conclusion

          if (GeneratedNumber <= 10) {

              conclusion = "The number generated 'numbervar' is less than or equal to 10";

          } else {

              conclusion = "The number generated “numbervar” is greater than 10";

          }

          document.getElementById("numText").innerText = conclusion;

      }

  </script>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.innerHTML` should be `.textContent`.

Comment: True, that's a bit safer. Changed it. But in his case it doesn't really matter, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: It does matter because when the text to be set/gotten doesn't contain any HTML, you are engaging the HTML parser  and modifying the DOM for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

You were defining your variable inside the random number calculation, so I just separated these.

```js
function ranNum() {
  var GeneratedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
  var ranNumber = document.getElementById("ranNumber");

  ranNumber.innerHTML = GeneratedNumber;

  var conclusion

  if (GeneratedNumber <= 10) {
    conclusion = "The number generated 'numbervar' is less than or equal to 10 "

  } else {

    conclusion = "The number generated “numbervar” is greater than 10 "

  }

  document.getElementById("numText").innerHTML = conclusion;

}
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="ranNum()" value="Generate Random Number 
    Between 1 and 20" />

<p id="ranNumber"></p>
<p id="numText"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this helped a lot with my understanding a various ways this same question can be resolved.